# Use spring integration command bus to start/stop AbstractEndpoints defined via Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-annotations

I used annotations to define inboundChannelAdapter. 
MyConfig.java

```
      @Bean
      @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "5000"),
          autoStartup = "true")
      public MessageSource<File> input() {
        final FileReadingMessageSource result = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        result.setDirectory(new File("src/main/java/test"));
        return result;
      }
```

I tried stopping it with :

```
 MessageChannel controlChannel = ctx.getBean("controlBusChannel", MessageChannel.class);
      AbstractPollingEndpoint endpoint = ctx.getBean("myConfig.input.inboundChannelAdapter", AbstractPollingEndpoint.class);
      if(endpoint.isRunning()){
        controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@"+endpoint.getComponentName()+".stop()"));
      }
```

But I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor@11b2519] (controlBus)]; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 10): Property or field 'input' cannot be found on object of type 'test.commandbus.MyConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11f6b4ee' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at test.commandbus.Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 10): Property or field 'input' cannot be found on object of type 'test.commandbus.MyConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11f6b4ee' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:150)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    ... 7 more
```

Is there a way to stop the adapter without having to define a specific @Bean for that ?

Comment: Your have the spring bean  with name 'input', but SPEL looking for property or field 'input'.

Comment: Try to expose your FileReadingMessagSource as Lifecycle (not MessageSource ) to provide start and stop methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for you is like:

```
"@'"+endpoint.getComponentName()+"'.stop()"
```

to make it look like in the end:

```
@'myConfig.input.inboundChannelAdapter'.stop()
```

Otherwise we have this SpEL:

```
@myConfig.input.inboundChannelAdapter.stop()
```

So, it evaluates `myConfig` bean and tries to get access to its `input` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem